# Highlight a particular plot among multiple plots

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I've made a plot using a data frame and ggplot. Here's the plot for example[image]

I'll be using this in a presentation. In one slide, I'm going to talk about epsilon=0.1, and in the next I'll be talking about epsilon=0.5. My question is: How do I make one particular plot thicker? i.e. I wish to create a plot where the orange graph corresponding to epsilon=0.1 is thick (and thus highlighted), so the audience knows that is the graph I'm referring to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would do is add an additional column to the data, `thickness`, which you can assign to the `size` aesthetic of `geom_line`. You simply assign a higher value to the values in `thickness` where `epsilon` equals 0.1:

```
df$thickness = ifelse(df$epsilon == 0.1, 2, 1)
```

and use it in `aes()` of `geom_line()`:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x,y,color=as.factor(epsilon))) + 
       geom_line(aes(size = thickness)) + scale_size_identity()
```

You can simply change the value in the call to `ifelse` to change which line get's highlighted. Note the use  of `scale_size_identity` to prevent ggplot from scaling the values, and simply using the values in `thickness` as such.

An example with the built-in dataset `mtcars`:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg, color = factor(cyl))) + 
       geom_line(aes(size = ifelse(mtcars$cyl == 6))) + 
       scale_size_identity()
```

[image]